# PHP know if someone is following another user Twitter API

Tags: php, api, twitter

I need to know if the user (A) that retweets is following the person who has retwitted (B). 
The [following=>] value tells if that user is following the person who created the app (token,secrect,etc)
I would create an array of people following B and compare it with the name of A but if he has too many followers is really hard.
I could check if A is following B but if the number of Retweets is huge I have the same problem.

Any ideas?

To resume: A person tweeted and got retweets. This person logs in my web (I get his token and secret) and he want to know if the people who retwitted his tweet is following him. With the problem that he has a lot of followers and retweets.